# JOIN with OR condition and use only MIN(Column)

Tags: sql, t-sql, join, aggregate

I have two tables. Certain values from table `t` need to be matched with certain values of table `m` in order to identify a target value from table `m`.

Table `t` looks as follows.

```
ID | A | B | C 
1  | x | y | z
2  | 1 | 2 | 3
```

Table `m` looks as follows.

```
matchA | matchB | matchC | priority | targetValue
NULL   | y      | NULL   | 1        | this
NULL   | NULL   | z      | 2        | that
```

The logic should be as follows: Column `A` from table `t` should be matched with column `matchA` from table `m` and so on. As you can see in the example, there can be multiple matches. In the first row of table `t` the value `y` of column `B` matches with the `y` of first row of table `m` in column `matchB`. However, the first row of table `t` also matches with the second row of table `m` with the `z` value in columns `C` and `matchC`. If this is the case, only the match with the lowest `priority` should be returned in the resultset. The value of the column `targetValue` should be shown.

I know how to do the matching, but I don't know how to filter down to just the result with the lowest priority.

This is what I have so far.

```
SELECT * FROM t
    INNER JOIN m
        ON m.matchA = t.A
        OR m.matchB = t.B
        OR m.matchC = t.C
```

This returns both matching rows. However, I only want the match with the lowest value in the column `priority`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a good use-case for a lateral join -- or `APPLY` in the language of SQL Server:

```
SELECT t.*, m.*
FROM t OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT TOP (1) m.*
      FROM m
      WHERE m.matchA = t.A OR
            m.matchB = t.B OR
            m.matchC = t.C
      ORDER BY m.Priority
     ) m
```